# Fancybox 3 not removing touch feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

On click of an area, a Fancybox(v3) is opened up which I have an option of `touch:false` to prevent the user from swiping Fancybox away as this is causing issues with the Datetime picker that is used within the Fancybox. 
Below I have the following:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    type: "ajax",
    src: "/forms/add_user_to_session.php",
    ajax: { 
        settings: { 
            data : data, 
            type : 'POST'
        }
    },
    opts: { 
        touch : false 
    }
});
```

But for some reason, the `touch:false` does not make any difference I have tried putting `touch:false` outside of the opts but still no change. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think *touch* has to be one level higher, like this:

```
$.fancybox.open({
  type: "ajax",
  src: "/forms/add_user_to_session.php",
  ajax: {
    settings: {
      data: data,
      type: "POST"
    }
  },
  touch: false
});
```

Here the codepen I tested with: https://codepen.io/Sixl/full/JxpwxY